# Joomla table DESCRIBE

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, database

I'm trying to DESCRIBE a table in joomla 3.x  I want to get the column names and the associated details (type etc) into an array.

I want to get

Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Comments    Extra

for any given table

I can't find anything in Joomla that tells me how to do that I think the way to go is to use DESCRIBE but I can't find anything in the API that allows me to do DESCRIBE.  I've tried lots of ways of getting the info but no success e.g:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);   
$query = "DESCRIBE `##__table_person`";
$row = $db->loadObjectList($query);
/*while($row ) {
    echo "{$row['Field']} - {$row['Type']}\n";
}*/
print "<pre>";
print_r($row);
print "</pre>";
exit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return an array of objects:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$result = $db->setQuery('DESCRIBE ' . $db->quoteName('#__table_person'))->loadObjectList();
```

Use `loadAssocList()` instead of `loadObjectList()` to return an array of associated arrays.